# Jquery On Click Method Not Working for Newly Added Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I have written some code that on the click of a button adds a new tweet(div) to a list of divs. See shortened code below. Now even though the new div has all the same classes as the other divs. It does not perform when clicked.

How can I get the jquery click method to work for newly added divs?

```
$('.buttonClass').on('click', function() {

    ....
              $newTweet.insertAfter('button');
    });



$('.douglascalhoun').on('click', function() {
          $("div").slideToggle();
          $("div.douglascalhoun").slideDown();
        });
```

Comment: @ShaunakD sorry, i just checked it .

Comment: I like the answer by Milind below, just tried it and it seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use event delegation for attaching events to dynamically generated elements:

```
$('body').on('click', '.douglascalhoun',function() {
      $("div").slideToggle();
      $("div.douglascalhoun").slideDown();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Milind! Appreciate it - this works :)

Answer (score 0):

behind the curtains event delegation works as follows for dynamically generated elements

```
$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {
  // Your Function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, when you are performing events when added dynamically.

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', function(){
     //from dynamic div
})
```